# Por que as constantes da classe File não seguem a convenção de constantes?

Tags: java, constantes, convenções

A convenção para constantes em Java diz que uma constante deve ser declaradas apenas com letras maiúsculas e as palavras devem ser separadas por *underscore* (_).

A declaração de uma constante é feita pela sequência das palavras-chave `static` e `final`. Ex: `public static final String NOME_COMPLETO = "José da Silva";`

---

A classe [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) possui suas constantes declaradas em *camelCase*. Ou seja, não segue a convenção. Várias outras classes da própria Oracle seguem a convenção.

Por que essa é diferente? Tem alguma outra convenção que "sobrescreve" essa? Ou a convenção foi ignorada?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Agora vi, talvez se deve pelo fato dessas variáveis não ter um valor já definido antes da classe ser iniciada. Olhe o que a definição das 3 variáveis diz: `The system-dependent[...]`, ou seja, o valor só é definido ao se usar a classe, para o compilador identificar qual é o seu SO.

Comment: @diegofm Boa! Então existe uma outra convenção para esse caso?

Comment: Muito provavelmente. As 3 variáveis não fazem parte dos  [campos constantes com valores predefinidos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html).

Comment: @diegofm Legal. Isso aparenta ser a resposta. Se tiver certeza, poderia responder, por favor?

Comment: Eu já li em algum lugar que há muita inconsistência mesmo por acidente. Não sei se é tanto o caso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Na verdade estas variáveis não são constantes, são variáveis com uma referência final, obtida provavelmente quando esta classe é utilizada, uma vez que o separador é definido conforme o sistema operacional em execução.

Isso fica mais óbvio olhando no [código-fonte da classe](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/File.java), como estas variáveis são declaradas:

```
public static final char pathSeparatorChar = fs.getPathSeparator();

public static final String pathSeparator = "" + pathSeparatorChar;

public static final String separator = "" + separatorChar;

public static final char separatorChar = fs.getSeparator();
```

Perceba que `separatorChar` e `pathSeparatorChar` tem seus valores definidos por referência recuperados do `FileSystem`, que é a classe que armazena informações sobre o sistema de arquivos local do sistema onde o compilador está em execução.

Logo, essas variáveis acabaram seguindo o padrão de convenção de variáveis `camelCase`, por não se tratarem de constantes.

Como pode ser visto [neste link da documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.io), há uma lista contendo todas as constantes da API do java, e pode-se observar que todas seguem o padrão de nomenclatura para constantes, e as variáveis da classe `File` não se encontram nesta lista.

**Referências:**

- [Should a “static final Logger” be declared in UPPER-CASE?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1417216/5524514)
- [Java naming convention for static final variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7259738/5524514)
- [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Vê algum motivo para não serem métodos ao invés de variáveis?

Comment: @IgorVenturelli acredito que seja para facilitar o uso, apesar que isso pode ter sido uma questão de gosto dos desenvolvedores do java. Sem contar que ao ver algo como `path = "path" + File.separator + "file;"` me parece bem mais agradável de se ler do que `path = "path" + File.getSeparator() + "file;"`

Comment: Sim. Mas da forma que está implementado aparenta ser bem mais familiar ás propriedades do C# do que a desenvolvimento Java mesmo. Por mais que seja "feio", o `getSeparator()` seria algo bem próximo ao dia a dia do dev Java, concorda?

Comment: @IgorVenturelli Aparentemente esse método já existe como abstrato na classe `FileSystem`, talvez podem ter evitado criar na classe File pra evitar redundâncias, já que as duas estão relacionadas entre si.

Comment: @IgorVenturelli motivo para ser campo `final` no lugar de método: são valores costumeiramente consumidos, então o acesso direto ao campo é mais performático. Como é muito usado, essa pouca diferença pode ser crucial

Comment: @IgorVenturelli , pode não ter sido essa a intenção original, mas performance é uma desculpa boa ;-)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado boa! Isso faz sentido, mas se é um campo estático, os valores serão ocupados na memória quando a classe for chamada e vai ficar lá até que a aplicação se encerre... Pode até ser mais performático, mas tem consumo maior de memória né :P Vale lembrar que estamos falando de 4 campos

Comment: Tentei achar do Java, mas serve como metáfora: http://www.alltechflix.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/why-chrome-eats-too-much-ram.jpg