# Constantes de tipos não primitivos

Tags: java, referência, constantes

Em Java, constantes são declaradas com a sequências das *keywords* `static` e `final`.

Quando temos `public static final int UM = 1;` "faz sentido" chamar de constante, uma vez que seu *valor* não pode ser alterado.

Agora, falando de tipos não primitivos, ainda "faz sentido" chamar de constante, uma vez que seus atributos podem ser alterados através de métodos?

A única coisa que fica constante é a referência, não os valores dos atributos.

---

Até hoje não precisei criar uma constante de tipo não primitivo (confesso que não via sentido para isso), mas vendo [esse código](https://github.com/caelum/caelum-stella/blob/master/stella-core/src/main/java/br/com/caelum/stella/DigitoGenerator.java#L6) no GitHub me veio a dúvida.

Comment: Meio duplicata: [Por que as constantes da classe File não seguem a convenção de constantes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219206/28595)

Comment: @Articuno não é. Fui eu mesmo quem fez essa pergunta

Comment: Eu sei, mas após ler essa, me pareceu a mesma duvida perguntada em outro cenario.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não.

O Maniero colocou uma resposta que explica os motivos técnicos para isso. Vou colocar aqui os motivos pelos quais o que o autor do código fez é errado.

O trecho relevante do código mencionado é esse:

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
```

A palavra-chave `final` garante que quem contém um valor ou referência não poderá mudá-lo após a inicialização - mas isso é desnecessário nesse caso, pois o campo acima já é privado. O autor do código só está protegendo seu código contra o próprio autor. Por ser privado, o campo só poderia ser alterado por método da própria classe (o que é uma decisão de quem for manter o código), ou por reflexão (que é o *cheat* supremo de qualquer forma).

Isso parece mais [excesso de engenharia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering), provavelmente fruto de comportamento condicionado. Isso ocorre, por exemplo, quando ouvimos coisas na faculdade como "sempre declare algo assim", "sempre use esse padrão" etc. e não questionamos o motivo.

---

Quanto a dúvida original, se o objeto seria uma verdadeira constante, visto que seus membros ainda poderiam ser alterados... Como o Maniero falou, talvez o desejo seja se ter algo imutável. Não me parece ser o objetivo do código relevante para a pergunta, pois o que o código se propõe a fazer é dar uma caixa-preta para a geração de números (pseudo-)aleatórios. De qualquer forma, o objeto `RANDOM` irá alterar seu estado interno a cada número obtido.

E finalmente, falando de uma forma conceitual... Se você tem um objeto constante e estático que possui membros imutáveis, você poderia cortar o intermediário e declarar os mesmos atributos do objeto imutável na classe que guarda sua instância. Assim você teria uma árvore mais rasa. Acho que salvo alguma necessidade muito específica isso seria mais direto e fácil de compreender.

Comment: Seguindo o que o @CarlosHeuberger disse, um membro estático pode sim ser acessado/manipulado por um membro não estático. O que não pode é o contrário.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger eu concordo sobre o acesso a variáve estática. Agradeço por me chamar a atenção, corrigi o erro. Agora sobre ter 38 autores - isso distribui a responsabilidade sobre as coisas, mas não a exime de ninguém.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger eu penso que outras pessoas podem usar o redistribuível de um código. Modificadores de acesso devem ser usados para controlar como outros projetos vão utilizar o que a gente faz, não para nos protegermos de nós mesmos.

Answer (score 8):

Primeiro, no meu entender Java não tem constante, tem campos estáticos que não podem ter seu valor alterado depois de definidos, o que por ser estático ocorrerá sempre antes de ser acessado a primeira. Não sei se Java tem alguma especificação que indica o momento exato da atribuição. Então pra mim o termo constante nem pode ser usado no caso mostrado na pergunta, ela é uma variável estática [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101).

Em C# existe variável imutável, estática ou não e constante que sempre é estática e garantidamente é o mesmo em toda execução (se o programador não fizer barbeiragem e usar constante como se fosse variável imutável). Claro que constante deve ser resolvida em tempo de compilação sempre, não pode ser inicializada depois, então nem todos os tipos podem ser usados.

Se isso não responde a pergunta como desejaria, então eu diria que um tipo por referência, chamado na pergunta de não primitivo<sup>*</sup>, colocado em uma variável `final`, que a torna imutável, poderia ser chamado de constante, independente de ser estática ou não, afinal se o termo é usado errado em variáveis estáticas, não vejo porque não usar em variáveis de instância. Então seria o valor indicado por aquele identificador, que é a referência para um objeto é "constante", mas o objeto apontado por ela pode ser variável.

Ter capacidade de variar é diferente de [ser uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). Assim como não ter a capacidade de variar não pode ser automaticamente considerado constante.

[Imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103460/101) é diferente de constância. Embora eu sabia que algumas pessoas possuem outro entendimento. Eu acho que a própria matemática não define bem o que é uma constante. [Existe algo que não varia no algoritmo e algo que não varia nunca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151721/101), que eu acho que é a verdadeira constante.

Não entrei no mérito disso ser desnecessário no código *linkado* na pergunta porque não é o foco dela, mas se quiser saber tem a resposta do Renan que é bem no estilo que gosto, desmistificando mitos.

<sup>*</sup> isso vai dar confusão quando Java futuro permitir tipos por valor não primitivos, por isso que eu falo pra sempre conceituar certo, mesmo quando parece que não precisa

Comment: Em outros termos, o que no Java chamamos de constantes são, na verdade, variáveis estáticas imutáveis?

Comment: @IgorVenturelli Isso, exatamente como está na resposta. Melhorei.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger E pomo definiria esses membros de estado que estão estáticos?

Comment: ah, é só uma questão linguística, bom o termo me parece ser esse então acho que por você não estar acostumado achou estranho. Pensei que o termo estivesse errado. Eu até prefiro usar campo, como em C#, mas em Java há preferência por atributo, então tento usar o que mais se usa em cada comunidade.